# SQL pivot query returns null on some columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following query that returns a car reg number together with the date it was seen and the location:

```
SELECT PLATE_READ.RegNumber, PLATE_READ.DateSeen, ANPR_CAMERA.Name FROM PLATE_READ

REG         DATESEEN               LOCATION
===         ========               ========
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:10:57    GIB EXIT
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:05:03    AIRPORT BARRIER
```

Rather than having three rows I would like to be able to query and have 1 row returned per registration number stating the dates it has been seen per location with the following format:

```
REG         GIB EXIT             AIRPORT BARRIER         
===         =============        ==============        
5897HHS     20/12/2013 12:10:57  20/12/2013 12:05:03
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT TOP(100) PLATE_READ.DateSeen,
    PLATE_READ.RegNumber,
    ANPR_CAMERA_GROUP.Name
  FROM ANPR_CAMERA
  INNER JOIN ANPR_CAMERA_GROUP
  ON ANPR_CAMERA.Id = ANPR_CAMERA_GROUP.Id
  INNER JOIN ANPR_CAMERA_IN_GROUP
  ON ANPR_CAMERA.Id        = ANPR_CAMERA_IN_GROUP.ANPRCameraId
  AND ANPR_CAMERA_GROUP.Id = ANPR_CAMERA_IN_GROUP.ANPRCameraGroupId
  INNER JOIN PLATE_READ
  ON ANPR_CAMERA.Id = PLATE_READ.CameraId
  ORDER BY PLATE_READ.DateSeen DESC
  ) x pivot ( MAX(DateSeen) FOR Name IN ([GIB EXIT], [AIRPORT BARRIER]) )p
```

However this is always returning a NULL value for the 'GIB EXIT' entry

Comment: It is returning `NULL` because there is no match in the data.  You need to check for leading and trailing spaces and other types of inequality.

Comment: There are no spaces and the data matches on all records as it is checked before being added.

Comment: Can you create a SQLFiddle with a sample of the data?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to build the scripts to test your example (which would have been helpful if you'd provided that), the answer became obvious.

You are selecting **ANPR_CAMERA**.Name in your first SQL, and **ANPR_CAMERA_GROUP**.Name in your pivot SQL.